# Find the probability of P(A)

Tags: probability

I have a problem I already know the answer to, but I do not know how to solve it or where to begin. The problem is:

> Given that $P(A ∪ B) = 0.76$ and $P(A ∪ B') = 0.87$, find $P(A)$.

The answer is $0.63$. Where should I begin?

Comment: You should start by obtaining a relationship for $A, A\cup B$ and $A\cup B'$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability that $A\cup B$ happens plus the probability that $A\cup B'$ happens is the probability that $A$ happens plus the probability that $B\cup B'$ happens.

Mathematically:

$$P(A\cup B) + P(A\cup B')=P(A)+P(B\cup B')$$
$$P(A\cup B) + P(A\cup B')=P(A)+1$$
$$P(A)=0.76+0.87-1=0.63$$

Comment: Very easy to follow through, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

$$P(A)+P(B)-P(A \cap B ) = 0.76$$
$$P(A) + P(B') -P(A \cap B') =0.87$$

Summing up the two equations,

$$2P(A)+1-P(A)=0.76+0.87$$
$$P(A)=0.76+0.87-1$$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $B^{\prime}$ is the complement of $B$, note that $(A\cup B)\cup (A\cup B^{\prime})=\Omega$ and that $(A\cup B)\cap (A\cup B^{\prime})=A$.

Moreover, for any events $E$ and $F$ we have
$$ \mathbb{P}(E\cup F)=\mathbb{P}(E)+\mathbb{P}(F)-\mathbb{P}(E\cap F) $$
So apply this with $E=A\cup B$ and $F=A\cup B^{\prime}$.